# How to maximise experience from Victini in Pokemon Shuffle?

Tags: pokemon-shuffle

In Pokemon shuffle each Saturday you can battle Victini that gives a lot of experience.

I normally try to level up the pokemons I need for incoming challenges and I use the Experience x 1.5 and move +5 power up.

Is there a strategy to maximise the experience points? Of course defeating it is necessary to get a lot of xp but maybe there are other variables such as number of remaining moves, number of combos, total damage delivered or other variables influencing the experience.

Answer (score 3):

No, you always get 1000 exp points (previously 500 and 400 before that) from Victini. If you defeat it, of course.
The only way to increase that amount is using *Experience x1.5* item, this will reward 1500 exp points to every Pokemon in your team, and 3000 exp points for the "crowned" one (the one that had the most icons removed during play).

Moves left, combos and damage don't affect the experience earned.

If you lose, your team will earn only a part of those 1000 experience points in relation to the percentage of damage done. And no one will receive the double crown bonus.